# Django Authenticate method not working on User class which extends "AbstractUser"

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication, django-users

It is a simple view, i have made the following model for users of the college website:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    year = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(4), MinValueValidator(1)], blank=False)
    Branch_CHOICES = (
    ('1', 'CSE'),
    ('2', 'ECE'),
    ('3', 'IT')
    )
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=Branch_CHOICES)
    rollNo = models.CharField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(5)], max_length=5, unique=True)
```

In case needed for reference,this is how i am registering the user (The redirect URL returned successfully logs in the user, but when i log out and try to log in back, the authentication fails):

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        rollno = request.POST["rollNo"]
        year = request.POST["Year"]
        form = registerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            branch = form.cleaned_data['branch']
        else:
            return render(request, "events/register.html", {
                "message": "You didn't provide all the fields",
                "form": registerForm()
            })
        email = str(rollno) + '@iiitu.ac.in'

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "events/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match.",
                "form": registerForm()
            })

        if not username or not rollno or not year or not password:
            return render(request, "events/register.html", {
                "message": "Please enter all the fields",
                "form": registerForm()
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)    
            user.rollNo = rollno
            user.branch = branch
            user.year = year
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "events/register.html", {
            "message": "Username already taken.",
            "form": registerForm()
        })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("events:index"))
    else:
        ctx = { "form": registerForm() }
        return render(request, "events/register.html", ctx)
```

Finally, this is my login_view:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Attempt to sign user in
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("events:index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "events/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid roll number and/or password."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "events/login.html")
```

and my form from which i am taking input:

```
<form action="{% url 'events:login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input autofocus class="form-control" type="char" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <br>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

I have no idea what's going wrong here

Comment: Have you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat yes i have " AUTH_USER_MODEL = "events.User" "